# widget text not updating

Tags: java, android, widget

Code:

```
private static void setText(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, RemoteViews views, String txt){
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, txt);
    String h = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    if(h.length()==1) h = "0"+h;
    String m = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    if(m.length()==1) m = "0"+m;
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, "Legion19 - " + h + ":" + m);
    String players = "";
    if(Servicio.instancia!=null && Servicio.instancia.players!=null) {
        Log.d("Legion19", Servicio.instancia.players.toString());
        for (int x = 0; x != Servicio.instancia.players.size(); x++)
            players += Servicio.instancia.players.get(x) + "\n";
    }
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.listaJug, players);

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

appwidget_text and textView get updated, but listaJug no.
I don't know what's the problem, logs:

> 01-05 17:45:48.685 2496-2496/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
>   01-05 17:45:48.685 2496-2496/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
>   01-05 17:45:48.685 2496-10360/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
>   01-05 17:45:49.960 1452-1480/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 9035474 , only wrote 9035280
>   01-05 17:45:49.961 10131-10131/xyz.legion19.legion19 D/Legion19: [SrAnGelXr3, Noemar19, ROXOLIN, rogermiranda1000]

online_players.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#09C"
android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#09C"
    android:text="Cargando..."
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listaJug"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appwidget_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/appwidget_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: First, you are missing toString() after get(x) here: `players += Servicio.instancia.players.get(x) + "\n";`. Then please log your players variable. And if it is really not null, post your layout xml.

Comment: The Servicio.instancia.players are a String list.

Comment: I put the xml in the main info

Comment: Ok, looks fine. Please add `Log.d(“Yourtext“, players);` directly before `views.setTextViewText(R.id.listaJug, players);` What is your log?

Comment: players it's not "", the variable works.
First >> [rogermiranda1000, Dondanunucus]
Second >> rogermiranda1000 [enter] 
Dondanunucus